# Как сделать "светящиеся" кнопки в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Чтоб вид был посовременнее, а не квадратное и серое? Я использовал Delphi 7. Может, для этого нужно использовать другую версию?

Comment: Если речь не о какой-то полноэкранной игрушке или подобном (и не о несоответствии системному стилю) — лучше не надо. От зоопарка «нескучных оформлений» у пользователей в глазах рябит. IMHO, намного лучше когда все в один (системный) стиль.

Но, да, про manifest в XP/Vista/7 Вам правильно говорят, если Delphi еще использует старый стиль времен Windows 9x/2000, а не современный — это оно, то что как раз стоит делать.

Answer (score 7):

В 7ке вы можете подключить специальный файл манифеста в приложение, благодаря чему оно будет использовать визуальное оформление операционной системы. Почитать об этом можно например тут: http://www.programmon.ru/Delphi7prof/6.html

Кроме того, вы всегда можете купить красивые компоненты типа [TMS](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/products.asp?t=vclp) или [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/). Они не так и дороги по сравнению с ценой самого Delphi )

Answer (score 2):

Для семерки есть и куча бесплатных "красивостей", типа Raize или JVCL библиотек. По мне так Raize выглядит наиболее приятным и современным вариантом, от которого (при грамотном использовании), в глазах рябить точно не будет )))